# Untie text field's icon click enabling from the input one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to implement an input field that can be unlocked by the user if needed.

Visually, I was thinking that the button should be either outside or inside the field but strongly linked to it.

To do so, I have been using the [Vuetify Text Field's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields) `append-outer-icon` props :

The template :

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="message"
  :append-outer-icon="icon"
  @click:append-outer="locked = !locked"
  :disabled="locked"
></v-text-field>
```

And here is the script :

```
data: () => ({
  message: '',
  locked: true,
}),
computed: {
  icon () {
    return this.locked ? 'lock' : 'lock_open'
  }
},
```

Here's the link to the Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQaJPK

However, the button cannot be clicked when the input is disabled.

Is there any way to have the button enabled while the input is not using this method or am I forced to separate the button and the input ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the CSS which prevents icon's click events:

```
.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--is-readonly) .v-icon.v-icon--disabled {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

---

Or for additional customization you can put icon inside the `append-outer` slot (there is also `append` slot for "inner" HTML), add custom icon class and override CSS which prevents clicking.

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="message"
  :disabled="locked"
>
  <v-icon 
      slot="append-outer" 
      @click="locked = !locked"
      class="lock-button"
  >
    {{ icon }}
  </v-icon>
</v-text-field>
```

So then also you can add `color="black"` on `v-icon` for example so it doesn't look disabled.

CSS:

```
.lock-button {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQqoYx)

Comment: Thanks ! But both of those solutions implies modifying the CSS, and I am strongly against that since it can break at every Vuetify update.

Comment: @ThomasFerro Edited. With custom class it shouldn't break, but need to use slot for it.

Comment: the `v-icon` element has the disabled attribute, to make this even simpler there is now no need to change CSS. (This may be an addition to the library since this question was asked).

Comment: Override the input does not work for me but pointer-events: auto; does

Answer (score 0):

i might be a little late, but i juste faced this problem, and what you *were* looking for is the prop **readonly**

```
 <v-text-field
    v-model="pseudo"
    :readonly="!locked"
    :append-icon="locked ? icon : icon2"
    @click:append="appendIconClick"
 />
```

To anyone reading this, something like that will make the text input disabled until the icon is clicked